# What is the best data structure to use for type-based querying?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures, complexity-theory

I am in the process of making a game, and in that process I have come across a bit of a problem.

I have many different types of game elements. These are all of type `Entity`.

There are many types of Entities, including ones that are visible and need to be drawn on the screen. These entities are of type `VisibleEntity` which extends `Entity`.

Like this, I have many different hierarchical types for the elements in the game.

My question is this:

What data structure has the best run-time complexity when issuing the following types of queries?

1) get objects of type `Entity`

2) get objects of type `VisibleEntity`

3) get objects of type `SomeSpecificGameObject`

The trivial solution is to store them all in a list, and iterate through them all, and if they are of the type specified, add them to a list that is to be returned.

Obviously, it is not feasible when computation is done at every frame for certain elements in the screen.

What is the best way to keep track of all this?

I appreciate any response!

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how Entities are created? Individually, or in batches? And how are they retrieved, all at once by type or by type and some other criteria? Are the entities related as objects, rather than classes in a hierarchy? My initial suggestion is a trie corresponding to the class hierarchy, so that all child nodes are either of the type queried or a subclass, just recurse to the appropriate class from the root node.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will try out several of the suggestions and see the best way to do this.

Comment: And for your initial question, they entities are created both individually and in batches. As for the requests, for things like physics, I will need to request things that can have physics applied to them; for collision, I will need to request things that have collible info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other trivial solution is to maintain one list per type. Store each list in a hashmap, with the type as the key. It's about as instant as you can get, and will only cost you one pointer per item. It also makes it possible to add the same object to more than one list. That will handle your hierarchy.

If you want to reduce the space required by the approach above, have each list-of-entities object also store pointers to the lists of its subclasses. That way, a VisibleEntity would live only in the VisibleEntity list, and not in the lists for its subclasses. To find all VisibleEntities, you do a hash lookup for the the main list, and then do a recursive search through the children for the subclasses. This is a simple tree structure.

```
class MyEntityList {
    List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList();
    List<MyEntityList> subclassLists = new ArrayList();
}
```

Depending on the height of your tree and the number of objects, you might be better off with the first approach. It's a complexity vs time vs space tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks! Your edit suggests something similar to a trie structure that JRideout suggested in the comment section.

Comment: It's not really a trie, or even a tree. It's a flat hashmap, with pointers to traverse upward. It's a simpler scheme.

Comment: Hmm. I don't quite understand why VisibileEntity list needs to keep track of its parent. Can you explain that again? Wouldn't the parent need to keep track of the children?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. To do the query "get objects of type VisibleEntity", you would need the subclasses, not the super class. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks user237815. I will most likely use this option. I also am going to optimize by using LinkedLists because joining two linked lists together is actually O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that using a class hierarchy to indicate whether or not an object has a certain attribute or not is the best idea.

You might want to keep objects that could be rendered in the game engine in an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), and certainly they will need to have some way of being drawn; so that may be a good candidate for a type (in the sense that an interface is a type).

As to other arbitrary attributes, you can represent them generically and then maintain indices for quick retrieval, or like you said, keep them in lists and have a simple filter function that can return you a sub-set of objects that match specific criteria. If there aren't too many objects then the second approach ought to work fine. The threshold value for 'too many' is a value that you'll probably have to figure out with some testing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to have to iterate through a list and generate a subset, although you may be right in that the threshold may not be reached, I want this to be scalable for many entities. I currently am doing this now, but I want to do better.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, it is not feasible when computation is done at every frame for certain elements in the screen.

That really depends on the number of objects. A modern cpu cycles several billion times each second. Assuming the check and add to the list takes 10 cycles and you do 100 frames per second, iterating over a list of 1000 elements for each frame will cause a cpu utilization of 0.1%. So on the contrary, the naive solution is very feasible unless you have thousands of game objects, or need to query by type many times per frame. The recommandation, as usual, is to implement the simplest thing that could possibly work, measure the performance impact, and optimize only if that impact is significant.

That said, the next simplest thing is to do:

```
abstract class Entity {
    private static Map<Class<?>, Set<? extends Entity>> byType = new HashMap<>();

    public static <E extends Entity> Set<E> allOfType(Class<E> clazz) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<E> set = (Set<E>) byType.get(clazz);
        if (set == null) {
            set = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
            byType.put(clazz, set);
        }
        return set;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected Entity() {
        for (Class c = getClass(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            allOfType(c).add(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected void destroy() {
        for (Class c = getClass(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            allOfType(c).remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

which you'd use like

```
for (VisibleEntity ve : Entity.allOfType(VisibleEntity.class)) {
    ve.render();
}
```

The approach can be generalized to index by things other than classes, simply use another key type for the map, and insert and remove from the category sets at appropriate times.

Comment: I like this method because the retrieval complexity is constant, with respect to the number of objects, since you amortize the adding and removing into the lists. Is there a way to not store the entries in multiple lists?